# How to move stack object into std::shared_pointer without instantiation

Tags: c++, scope, shared-ptr

### Question

Hi there. I have a bit weird question. Suppose you have a non-copiable stack object, which you have gotten from an external library. How is it possible to move the content into a heap object allocated by `std::make_shared` without actually instantiating the class?

```
class my_class {
private:
  my_class(my_class const&) = delete;

public:
  my_class(some_arg_t some_args);
  my_class(my_class&& move);
}

// later on

std::unordered_set<std::shared_ptr<my_class>> shared_pointers_container;

int foo() {
  my_class obj = getMyClassObject();
  shared_pointers_container.insert(// moving obj into heap memory and get the shared pointer to it)
}
```

One "solution" could be to create an instance of the object and then replace it, like shown below

```
  std::shared_ptr<my_class> ptr = std::make_shared<my_class>(arguments_needed);
  *ptr.get() = std::move(obj);
  shared_pointers_container.insert(ptr);
```

but it's not a good solution (in case the constructor does some changes).

Maybe a way to tell `std::make_shared` to move the content of newly created object from the specified object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done. No tricks needed. Just move the object:

```
shared_pointers_container.insert(std::make_shared<my_class>(getMyClassObject()));

// or if you need to start from `obj`:

my_class obj = getMyClassObject();
// work with obj
shared_pointers_container.insert(std::make_shared<my_class>(std::move(obj)););
```

---

On your remarks:

> without actually instantiating the class?
>
> (in case the constructor does some changes).

This is completely unreasonable. If the constructor doesn't do what it is supposed to do then the class is buggy.

To be more clear: the problem you are trying to solve is this: You have an object given by value from an external library. This object is move-only. You want to put this object into a container of shared pointers. This is the problem. In solving this problem you think you cannot use the move constructor but that is definitely not the case. The solution is to use the move constructor how I showed.

Comment: what is the issue with my answer?

Comment: You instantiate a new object. You just move construct it from `obj`. This does not answer the question

Comment: I think he doesn't instantiate a new one but moves the old one

Comment: @sparik ofc I do that. And it answers the question. That is how it should be done. If you could be more specific on how this doesn't answer the question?

Comment: You are obviously instantiating an instance of `my_class`. It's just that the constructor used is the move constructor.

Comment: @sparik yes. And how is that a problem?

Comment: 'without actually instantiating the class'  was specifically mentioned. Maybe I just misunderstood the question. If that's the case, I'm sorry.

Comment: I think you did misunderstand the answer. It doesn't create a fully new object. It constructs the new one using the move constructor, which fits the question.

Comment: I didn't say, that the move constructor does changes, but the object constructor does.

Comment: @sparik ok, I agree that's strictly what the OP wants. However I am telling that he/she doesn't really want that, it's a requirement that makes not sense and the solution is what I present. The OP is missguided in thinking he/she cannot instantiate a new object and move into it

Comment: @arsdever I instantiate a new object and initialize it by moving from the old one.

Comment: @bolov I understand and agree, don't worry

Comment: @arsdever of course it does :) it is a fully new object in a completely different memory location, etc. Anyway, I'm happy your problem is solved. @bolov I initially thought OP asked if he can pass the ownership of `obj` (specifically) to a shared_ptr without any new instantiation of my_class, which is impossible because `obj` has automatic storage duration. Anyway, I removed my downvote :)

Comment: I don't understand - who downvoted this answer, cause this answers my question. Thanks @bolov.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you need it for some reason, here's a trick that works for a class that's neither movable nor copyable. It's kind of horrifying; I wouldn't recommend it in practice.

```
class Wrapper {
    std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(my_class), alignof(my_class)> data;
public:
    Wrapper() { new(&data) my_class{getMyClassObject()}; }
    ~Wrapper() { get()->~my_class(); }
    my_class* get() { return reinterpret_cast<my_class*>(&data); }
};

int main()
{
    auto wp = std::make_shared<Wrapper>();
    std::shared_ptr<my_class> p(wp, wp->get());
}
```

[Demo](https://rextester.com/OGS47189).

This relies on the little-known feature of `std::shared_ptr`, where it can manage one object but expose a pointer to another (usually the sub-object of the first object).

Comment: this doesn't work `new(&data) my_class{getMyClassObject()}` requires `my_class` to be copyable or movable

Comment: @bolov Not any more than `my_class obj = getMyClassObject();` does. Both rely on guaranteed copy elision in C++17. Look at the demo - I explicitly deleted both copy and move constructors, and yet it compiles and runs (with `-std=c++17` but not with `-std=c++14`)

Comment: oh yeah. You should add that it requires C++17

Comment: @bolov Again, so does `my_class obj = getMyClassObject();` The problem statement doesn't make sense pre-C++17.

Comment: in the OP example the object is movable.

Comment: @bolov Right. I strengthened the problem statement to "a class that's neither movable nor copyable". If the object can be moved, then the problem is trivial and no longer interesting, and in any case your answer already addresses this case.

Comment: Your answer seems quite difficult and unfamiliar to me. I must dive into to understand. BTW thanks for pointing it out.